# Passing a list in hql query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

I am not getting output when I am directly passing a list through IN clause, but getting output when passing the values separately.

Working Code below:

```
List<String> resultList = null;
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("123");
list.add("456"):
String query = "select * from company where id in('123','456')");
 resultList=getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, String.class);
```

Not working code:

```
List<String> resultList = null;
List<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("123");
list.add("456"):
String query = "select * from company where id in(:list)");
resultList=getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, String.class);
```

I want to fetch the query based on the list passed in the query. Could someone help me here

I have created a pojo class Company.java where I have mentioned db column fields.
After the query part,

```
List<Company> comp = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(query, Company.class);
```

Error I am getting :
Incorrect Column count: expected 1, actual 23

What changes I need to do in above line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute IN() SQL queries with Spring's JDBCTemplate effectivly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327074/how-to-execute-in-sql-queries-with-springs-jdbctemplate-effectivly)

Comment: Yes I got the correct result. But now I am trying to put those fields retrieved from query in a pojo class..

Comment: For ex: I have a pojo class Company and I want to store the result of query in pojo.. I tried one method but I am getting error.. please see my edited part above

Comment: Raise a new question instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33008205/6572971 this will help you.